# How to run vowpal wabbit after cygwin build?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, vowpalwabbit

I use cygwin to build vowpal_wabbit-7.3 on win xp sp3.

> ./configue
>
> make

It created folder vowpalwabbit with vw.exe but when I tried to run it give me error that cygwin1.dll not found, so how to properly use vowpalwabbit after it builded in cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was just add "C:\cygwin\bin" to Path.